# Is it possible for a behavior to specify a custom subform for fields which it adds

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm trying to create a behavior which adds 2 new fields to content types to which it is applied, but I'd like those fields to have a custom subform on the add/edit forms for content types it is added to. Is there any straightforward way to do this as part of the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fieldset inside your schema

```
from plone.directives import form
....
class IMyBehaviorSchema(form.Schema):

    form.fieldset('myfieldset', label=u"My Behavior fieldset",
                  fields=['firstfieldname', 'secondfieldname'])
```

to display your additional fields with Plone form tabbing enabled. See [Dexterity manual](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/behaviors/schema-only-behaviors) for further information

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I meant by subform. I mean a z3c.form subform with its own template, as described here: http://packages.python.org/z3c.form/subform.html